# How to declare newline character variable in Liquid template?

Tags: html, jekyll, liquid

I want to do something like this:

```
{% assign newline = "\n" %}
newline = '{{xxxx}}'
```

But this returns the output as:

```
newline = '\n'
```

I expect output as:

```
newline = '  
'
```

Comment: Why did you want to do this ? Can you give us more code to clearly undertand ?

Comment: I want to minify HTML and CSS for my blog site (built with jekyll). Right now, I am using a kind of hack - loading another file and removing the characters to get new line character.
{% capture my_include %}
  {% include newline_hack.txt %}
{% endcapture %}
{% assign newline_char = my_include | replace: 'line1', '' | replace: 'line2', '' %}

Comment: newline_hack.txt - https://github.com/rohit01/rohit01.github.io/blob/master/_includes/newline_hack.txt
Minify code: https://github.com/rohit01/rohit01.github.io/blob/master/_layouts/minify.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid you cannot use the "\n" which is a regular expression piece that cannot be parsed by regular Jekyll filters.

But you can find another way.

### Compressing css

You can use native Jekyll sass converter.

- Rename your _includes/css/styles.css to css/styles.scss
- Add a front matter to it

  ```
  ---
  # this yaml front matter, even empty, forces Jekyll to parse sass or scss
  # you can put plain css in this file, it will simply benefit from
  # compression functionalities
  ---
  html,body,div,span ....
  ```
- configure you sass behavior in _config.yml

  ```
  sass:
    # style : nested (default), compact, compressed, expanded
    #         :nested, :compact, :compressed, :expanded also works
    # see http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#output_style
    # on a typical twitter bootstrap stats are :
    # nested 138,7kB, compact 129,1kB, expanded 135,9 kB, compressed 122,4 kB
    style: compressed
  ```

## compressing html

You just can use the [imathis html minification plugin](https://github.com/imathis/jekyll-minify-html).

You will then need to use a different workflow to publish your sources to Github pages.

You can find useful inspiration in [Octopress Rakefile](https://github.com/octopress/docs/blob/master/Rakefile) or in my [works on versioning workflows](https://github.com/djacquel/JekyllVersioningWorkflows) for sites using plugins.